# Jenkins Blue Ocean I cannot commit and push anything

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I just started to learn what Jenkins and how to use it. My research led me to the blue ocean to connect GitHub repositories to Jenkins. I can connect each other without having any problems. However, after I finish creating jenkinsfile in blue ocean, I cannot commit or push jenkinsfile to the repository. I get an error that says 'error indexing'. If I push the 'save & run' button again, I get an another error that says:

> PUT [https://api.github.com/repos/"organization-name"/"repo-name"/contents/Jenkinsfile](https://api.github.com/repos/%22organization-name%22/%22repo-name%22/contents/Jenkinsfile) returned error: 422. Error message: {"message":"Invalid request.\n\n"sha" wasn't supplied.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"}.'

So, please help me guys I will leave photos of errors below.

This is first Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2M8b.png

This is second one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUwwx.png

Comment: Interestingly despite those errors blue ocean can push Jenkinsfile into repositories

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post your images as code/text instead: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Jenkins Blue Ocean(especially for creating Pipelines) as it's not actively maintained. Blue Ocean will not be receiving any improvements or bug fixes. You can read about this from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/blueocean/). The following is from the official page.

> Blue Ocean will not receive further functionality
> updates. Blue Ocean will continue to provide easy-to-use Pipeline
> visualization, but it will not be enhanced further. It will only
> receive selective updates for significant security issues or
> functional defects.
>
> Alternative options for Pipeline visualization, such as the Pipeline:
> Stage View and Pipeline Graph View plugins, are available and offer
> some of the same functionality. While not complete replacements for
> Blue Ocean, contributions are encouraged from the community for
> continued development of these plugins.
>
> The Pipeline syntax snippet generator assists users as they define
> Pipeline steps with their arguments. It is the preferred tool for
> Jenkins Pipeline creation, as it provides online help for the Pipeline
> steps available in your Jenkins controller. It uses the plugins
> installed on your Jenkins controller to generate the Pipeline syntax.
> Refer to the Pipeline steps reference page for information on all
> available Pipeline steps.

Comment: This answer doesn't add much to the issue at hand, and there is no real alternative to Blue Ocean as of now.

Comment: @MaratC I do agree with you. I think the answer is, simply to use the classic view to create the Pipelines and to use one of the alternatives mentioned on the official page to view the builds. (Even blue ocean works fine when viewing simple builds)

Comment: The "Stage View" and "Graph View" are nowhere near the maturity of Blue Ocean and they aren't functioning on complicated builds. It's nice that they offer to play with that child shovels because the Caterpillar D9 is EOLed, but this advice is  nowhere near having any sense whatsoever. "Don't use Jenkins" is a more practical piece of advice.

Answer (score 0):

As ykursatkara pointed out. Although Blue Ocean shows those two errors in the Jenkins interface, the commit is performed and the `Jenkinsfile` gets changed. You should check in your repository whether the commit was applied or not and retry. No more than two attempts should be necessary.